# powershell Import-module from C# is always failing

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I am using dot net version 4.5 and SCVMM 2012 R2. trying to run below code

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();

initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] { "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\\Virtual Machine Manager\\bin\\psModules\\virtualmachinemanager\\virtualmachinemanager.psd1" });
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
runspace.Open();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Get-SCVMMserver");
ps.AddParameter("ComputerName", "some.domain.com");

foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{                   
  Console.WriteLine(result.Members["IsSupported"].Value);
}
```

It always fails wit hthe following error,

> The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file:
>   Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 >R2\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\virtualmachinemanager.types.ps1xml(5) : Error >in type "Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VMCheckpoint": >Exception: Cannot convert the >"Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.VMCheckpointConverter"
>   value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
>   Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 >R2\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\virtualmachinemanager.types.ps1xml(11) : >Error in type "Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Task": >Exception: Cannot convert the >"Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.TaskConverter" value >of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".

please help me this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message states `Cannot convert the >"Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.TaskConverter" value >of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".` Just change the line 2 from `string[]` to `new[]` and it should be fine i think.

#### Like this

```
initial.ImportPSModule(new[] { "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\\Virtual Machine Manager\\bin\\psModules\\virtualmachinemanager\\virtualmachinemanager.psd1" });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the change did not solve the issue. I still get the same error. Please help me in this.